# C# - Win32 PostMessage Ctrl-C (copy) to not focused window

Tags: c#, copy, copy-paste, sendmessage, postmessage

I want to send a keycombination like Ctrl-C to a non focused window (game).

I've tried a lot of different ways, like sending "WM_COPY", "WM_GETTEXT", "WM_CHAR"+ 0x03 or using keybd_event to press Ctrl.
Nothing of this is working, but i'm able to PostMessage with "WM_KEYDOWN" and "WM_KEYUP".

So I've tried now to SetKeyBoardState and modify the Ctrl keystate and then sending a PostMessage, but it doesn't work, too.

Test with Ctrl-V:

```
//Some time to move mouse to the control
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); 

//Control pointer
IntPtr hWnd = WindowFromPoint(Control.MousePosition);

uint targetThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero);
uint myThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
AttachThreadInput(myThreadId, targetThreadId, true);

var keys = new byte[256];
GetKeyboardState(keys);

var key = (int)Keys.ControlKey;
var prevState = keys[key];
keys[key] = 128;

/* Test if ctrl pressed
if ((keys[key] & 0x80) != 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ctrl pressed");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ctrl not pressed");
}*/

SetKeyboardState(keys); 

PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, Convert.ToInt32(Keys.V), 0);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, Convert.ToInt32(Keys.V), 0);

keys[key] = prevState;
SetKeyboardState(keys);

AttachThreadInput(myThreadId, targetThreadId, false);
```

Maby someone has an idea?

Regards, Joie95

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can this really done by UI Automation, because it's a DirectX/OpenGL application where I like to copy some text? Spy++ only shows one class and no more information, so I don't think i'm able to find the textfield in the game.

Comment: UIA does not require a window, just a programmer that made his program accessible to the kind of programs that help people with a reading disability.  Like screen readers.  The odds that a game programmer did so are never very good.  They do however make an extra effort to ensure that simulating keyboard input will never work, punk-buster style.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said the textbox in the game recognizes the PostMessages   like pressing 'v'. And it's also possible to paste text into the textbox with pressing Ctrl+V manually.